# Equivalent definitions of Euler characteristic for closed manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, compact-manifolds

It is well-known that the Euler characteristic of a closed manifold $M^n$, which
can be defined as $\chi(M)=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \operatorname{dim}H^k(M)$, equals the
intersection number $I(\Delta,\Delta)$ of the diagonal with itself in $M\times M$. 
Is there a way to prove this without constructing triangulations? I am looking for a proof which uses only basic facts such as Poincaré Duality. Also notice that this identity is equivalent to the Poincaré-Hopf theorem.

Comment: you could use the euler class of the normal bundle of $\Delta \cong M$ in $M\times M$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you want to check. I'm thinking of deRham cohomology, but still writing $H^i(M)$ for $H^i(M,\Bbb R)\cong H^i_{\text{deRham}}(M)$; but it all works fine with cup product, too. We assume $M$ compact and oriented.

Let $\alpha_{i,j}$ ($j=1,\dots,\dim H^i(M)$) be a basis for $H^i(M)$, and let $\beta_{n-i,j}$ be the dual basis for $H^{n-i}(M)$, in the sense that $$\int_M \alpha_{i,j}\wedge\beta_{n-i,j} = 1 \text{ for all }i,j.$$
Note that $(-1)^{i(n-i)}\alpha_{i,j}$ is the dual of $\beta_{n-i,j}$.

By definition, the Poincaré dual of $\Delta\subset M\times M$ will be an $n$-form $\eta$ on $M\times M$ with the property that $$\int_\Delta \phi = \int_{M\times M} \phi\wedge\eta \text{ for every closed $n$-form $\eta$ on $M\times M$}.$$
Now you just have to do some careful sign-checking (keeping track of skew-commutativity) to verify that
$$\eta = \sum_{i,j} (-1)^i \pi_1^*\alpha_{i,j}\wedge\pi_2^*\beta_{n-i,j},$$
where $\pi_i$ are the obvious projections from $M\times M$ to $M$.
Since $\Delta\cdot\Delta = \displaystyle\int_\Delta \eta$, we just have to then check that
$$\int_\Delta\eta = \sum_i (-1)^i \dim H^i(M).$$
Letting $\iota\colon M\to M\times M$ be the diagonal inclusion, we have
$$\int_\Delta\eta = \int_M \iota^*\eta = \sum_{i,j} (-1)^i \sum_{j=1}^{\dim H^i(M)}\alpha_{i,j}\wedge\beta_{n-i,j} = \sum_i (-1)^i\dim H^i(M).$$

Comment: That can be found in Bott and Tu's Differential forms in algebraic topology, p.126

Comment: Ah, of course. When I thought through all this decades ago, it was before Bott and Tu. And I didn't have it here with me.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!